# Layout Issue - CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

**Html**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="headers">
        <header>
            <div id="Logo">
                <img alt="SiteLogo" src="Images/kas.png" style="width:130px;height: 55px;" />
            </div>
            <div id="LogoText">Camphor Works</div>
            <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Index.aspx">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx">ABOUT US</a>

        </li>
        <li class='has-sub '><a href="Products.aspx">PRODUCTS</a>

            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Services.aspx">SERVICES</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="Enquiry.aspx">ENQUIRY</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
        </header>
        </div>
        <section>
            <article id="Articleleft">

            </article>
            <article id="Articleright"></article>
        </section>
        <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            <div id="socialmedia"></div>
            <div id="QuickLinks"></div>
        </footer>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

For **Css** please check the fiddle..!!!

## Fiddle Demos

---

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JrbMm/)

## [Full page Result of the site](http://jsfiddle.net/JrbMm/embedded/result/)

**Issue**

As you can see in the full page result of the fiddle  `100% width` of header and footer doesn't occupies full page??

i have been spending nearly two days to figure it out but all in vain.

please help me out and also point out if there are any errors in the site.

**Edit:**
I want the header and footer to be fixed at the top and bottom respectively..!! they both should occupy the screen's whole width..!

But main section will be occupying the middle region alone..!

To be more Clear refer the image..!!

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be fullscreen to me (firefox) do you want to expand the `<section>` ?

Comment: no it is full screen, scroll it horizontally you will find empty spaces in the right..!

Comment: I analyse ur code, it has something to do with the nav

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML so what should i change?

Comment: im finishd the answere comes

Comment: try making it fixed the it will become full screen

Comment: Your `header` has a width of `1100px` while `<section>` is `1000px` wide. Is that intended ?

Comment: yes it is so..!! the header will occupy the whole screen whereas the section will be having in the middle..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V3kDd/3/embedded/result/)**
You have to change this in css:

```
nav ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 598;
    max-width: 100%; <-- from width to max-width
    max-height: 100%; <--- from height to max-height
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    min-width: 190px;
}
#############################
#footer
{
    padding:0px;
    height:150px;
    min-width:100%;
    width: 1000px;   <-------- here --------------
    clear:both;                                  -
    background-color:#333;                       -
    margin-top:10px;                             -
                                                 -
}                                                -
footer                                           -
{                                                -
    color:#ffffff;                               -
    width: 1000px; <--------- this have be to ----        
    bottom : 0;
    position:relative;
}
```

this will removed for header and for the footer.

[image]

Comment: can u add a comment or give a tick to my anwere that i know that i know my anwere was helpful @AmarnathBalasubramanian

Comment: hey it solved the issue of header but can u check the footer in fiddle? the width of footer is 100% in full size but when shinked it occupies the width of section..!! can you please check that too..!

Comment: as i said its a bug here a fullscreen solution in fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/V3kDd/embedded/result/

Comment: wait a while i will checked that again

Comment: still the same..!! :(

Comment: your edit has over come the section's width but still white space is there on the footer's right side

Comment: i do agree that.. but while minimizing it is collapsing..!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with your padding - once you use padding on the text in the nav - it effectively increases the with and creating that offset.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JrbMm/5/)

To answer your question of why you have that space gap between the border line and the top nav :: You have a `margin-top: 20px` on `section`

and if you want the footer to be "sticky" and fixed at the bottom add the following to `#footer`

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: does that make any sense?? no it didn't..!! :(